# libmysqlclient compile error: In function `yaSSLv3_server_method'

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors

I want to compile C files in ubuntu16.04, the makefile file is as follows:

```
TARGET  := matchengine.exe
INCS = -I ../network -I ../utils
LIBS = -L ../utils -lutils -L ../network -lnetwork -Wl,-Bstatic -lev -ljansson -lmpdec -lmysqlclient -lz -lrdkafka -lssl -lcrypto -lhiredis -Wl,-Bdynamic -lm -lpthread -ldl
include ../makefile.inc
```

I have installed libmysqlclient-dev and mysql-client library using following command:

```
apt install mysql-client-5.6
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

While I compiled the C files , the following errors show:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a(my_default.cc.o):(.data.DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0[DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a(ssl.cpp.o): In function `yaSSLv3_server_method':
(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a(ssl.cpp.o): In function `yaSSLv3_server_method':
(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a(ssl.cpp.o): In function `yaSSLv3_client_method':
(.text+0xe0): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a(ssl.cpp.o): In function `yaSSLv3_client_method':
(.text+0x121): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a(ssl.cpp.o): In function `yaTLSv1_server_method':
(.text+0x173): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
.....
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a(ripemd.cpp.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN8TaoCrypt9RIPEMD160E[_ZTIN8TaoCrypt9RIPEMD160E]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a(dh.cpp.o): In function `TaoCrypt::DH::GeneratePrivate(TaoCrypt::RandomNumberGenerator&, unsigned char*)':
(.text+0x122): undefined reference to `operator delete[](void*)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a(dh.cpp.o): In function `TaoCrypt::DH::GeneratePrivate(TaoCrypt::RandomNumberGenerator&, unsigned char*)':
(.text+0x145): undefined reference to `operator delete[](void*)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a(dh.cpp.o): In function `TaoCrypt::DH::GeneratePrivate(TaoCrypt::RandomNumberGenerator&, unsigned char*)':
(.text+0x162): undefined reference to `operator delete[](void*)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a(dh.cpp.o): In function `TaoCrypt::DH::GeneratePrivate(TaoCrypt::RandomNumberGenerator&, unsigned char*)':
(.text+0x1a0): undefined reference to `operator delete[](void*)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a(dh.cpp.o): In function `TaoCrypt::DH::GeneratePublic(unsigned char const*, unsigned char*)':
(.text+0x2b3): undefined reference to `operator delete[](void*)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a(dh.cpp.o):(.text+0x2d0): more undefined references to `operator delete[](void*)' follow
```

Comment: [How to format](/help/formatting)

Comment: Shifting `-lmysqlclient` to the end of `LIBS` fixed it for me